# "broken" windows xp after disc replacement

Tags: windows-xp, windows-activation

I had Windows XP Pro OEM installed on my machine. The disk was failing so I cloned it to a new disk (larger one).

Now Windows said that the hardware has changed significantly and I need to re-activate,
and I would gladly do so (got the product number on a sticker on the machine) - only that for running the activation process I need to be logged-in, but when I try to login it just automatically logs me out again.

I know my credentials are OK because I can connect to the machine remotely and also use sysinternals tools such as PsExec or PSList etc. on it from a remote machine by specifying user and password.

Login via safemode does not work any differently then in normal mode...

I tried to run `rundll32.exe syssetup,SetupOobeBnk` (as suggested in several places on the net) using PsExec but it did not seem to help...

Is there any way out of this evil circle? [ can't log in because not activated - can't activate because not logged in ]

Comment: How did you clone your old HDD?  I've used `regedit` to delete entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`/`SYSTEM`/`MountedDevices`, and then copied contents of partitions using `GParted`.

Comment: I used clonezilla.
Why do you need to change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/MountedDevices?

Comment: Because the Windows registry will otherwise contain disk IDs for your old HDD instead of your new HDD.  http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=14430

Comment: @sawdust - your comment was right on the spot. please post it as an answer and I will comment and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, copying a bootable Windows partition byte-for-byte without any modifications to another HDD will not be bootable.  I have not seen the login issue that you encountered, but rather the WinXP boot would hang at the blue-background "welcome" screen.

The proper way to copy the Win OS partition involves removing the (old, original) disk ID information stored in the registry.  For each Windows logical drive, there are two registry entries under
        `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ MountedDevices`
If any of these logical drives are assigned to partitions on the disk drive that you are replacing, then the two registry entries for those logical-drives/partitions should be deleted.

These registry entries are easily deleted prior to the HDD copy by **run**ning the Windows program `regedit`.
If the partition was copied with the registry intact with the original disk information, then a more complicated procedure for cleaning up the registry *after* the partition copy is described [here](http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=14430).

Windows will rebuild these `MountedDevices` entries after every boot (using a default ordering), so typically there is no harm in deleting them.

Comment: On my machine I the original HDD had 2 partitions (C & D). the cloned partitions on the target HDD where mounted as E & G (F was CD ROM). When I removed the original HDD and booted from the cloned HDD it picked up those drive letters (E & G) - so it actually booted from it but all the paths where wrong for it to actually work. I reconnected both drives, used regedit to `load Hive`  `e:\windows\system32\config\system` and at the `MountedDevices` key I deleted the values for `\DosDevices\C:` and `\DosDevices\D:` and renamed `\DosDevices\E:` to `...\C:` and `...\G:` to '...\D:'.

Comment: I then removed the original disk. booted and Voilà. I did need however to re-activate over the network but that went o.k. with not special issues.  I also recommend http://diddy.boot-land.net/firadisk/files/mounteddevices.htm as a good source for those seeking to better understand...

Comment: Although we and these guides only mention WinXP, I did use `regedit` on a **Windows 7** partition before copying it to another disk just the other day, and successfully booted Win7 from the copy.

Comment: And you suggest that next time this entire key can be safely removed before cloning and it will recreate with the new right values for the close when it initially boots. I will keep that in mind. many thanks.

Comment: Do not remove the entire registry key.  You can delete
all the values except the `default` line.